# Create separate log stream for each file with pattern AWS Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I wanna create separate log streams for each fille with pattern sync-*.log (for example filename sync-site1.log, stream name - server-sync-site1). There are a lot of log files with sync-*.log pattern, so do it manually for each is a bad option for me. How can I do it? I'm using an older agent.

Here is my current config:

```
[server-sync.log] 
datetime_format = %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S,%f
file = /home/ec2-user/log/sync/sync-*.log 
buffer_duration = 5000 
log_stream_name = server-sync
initial_position = end_of_file
multi_line_start_pattern = {datetime_format}
log_group_name = server
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a well defined API Call for this purpose [CreateLogStream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_CreateLogStream.html), corresponding api call in boto3 is [create_stream](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.create_log_stream)

```py
response = client.create_log_stream(
    logGroupName='string',
    logStreamName='string'
)
```

There is a terraform resource as well named [aws_cloudwatch_log_stream](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_log_stream)

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "yada" {
  name = "Yada"
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_stream" "foo" {
  name           = "SampleLogStream1234"
  log_group_name = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.yada.name
}
```